# How do you ack for a file that contains two or more phrases/words?

Tags: ack

How do you use `ack` to search for a file that contains, for example,

1. cat
2. dog
3. mouse

anywhere in the file? Each phrase *occur* at least once in the file.

This is kind of like the behavior of an online search engine.

**Bonus:**

1. Can we use regex on those individual phrase as well?
2. Or perhaps declare at least how many times a phrase must occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@kirkbauer suggested

```
ack phrase2 `ack -l phrase1`
```

and that will indeed work.  I prefer to use the `$()` syntax instead of ``` ` syntax

```
ack phrase2 $(ack -l phrase1)
```

With the release of ack 2.0, you get the `-x` switch so that you can do this:

```
ack -l phrase1 | ack -x phrase2
```

The `-x` tells ack to take the list of files to read from STDIN.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick: perform first ack, get file list, look for second set of files.

```
ack phrase2 `ack -l phrase1`
```